# How to reduce a list against another list of patterns?

Tags: ansible

I need to write with Ansible's built in [filters](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py) and [tests](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/test/core.py) the similar logic of shell one-liner:

```
for path in $(find PATH_TO_DIR); do for pattern in $PATTERNS; do echo $path | grep -v $pattern; done; done
```

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    paths:
      - "/home/vagrant/.ansible"
      - path-one
      - path-two
      - path-three
      - "/home/vagrant/.ssh"
      - "/home/vagratn/"
    patterns:
      - ".*ssh.*"
      - ".*ansible.*"
      - ".*one.*"

  tasks:
    - name: set empty list
      set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: [  ]
```

In the end I would like to have a list like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "path-two",
        "path-three",
        "/home/vagratn/"
    ]
}
```

With this form I getting a list where only last item from `patterns` is applied.

```
    - set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: |
          {{ paths
          |reject("search", item)
          |list }}
      with_items:
        - "{{ patterns }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks below do the job

```
    - set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: "{{ paths }}"
    - set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: "{{ files_to_be_removed|
                                 reject('search', item)|
                                 list }}"
      loop: "{{ patterns }}"
    - debug:
        var: files_to_be_removed
```

give

```
    "files_to_be_removed": [
        "path-two", 
        "path-three", 
        "/home/vagratn/"
    ]
```